# AWS - Amazon Polly Text To Speech

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, text-to-speech, amazon-polly

I have doubts about the **"text-to-speech"** **Amazon Polly** service. 
I've integrated this service in my chatbot, in order to describe vocally what the bot writes to the user in chat. 
It works pretty well, but I don't know if it is possible to stop the voice early, before *she* (I chose a female voice) finishes speaking. Sometimes I need to go further in the conversation and I don't want to listen until the end of the sentence.

This is the code used for the integration:

```js
//Html side
function textToSpeech(text) {
  $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: '/Chat/TextToSpeech?text=' + text,
    
    cache: false,
    success: function (result) {
    
      var audio = document.getElementById('botvoice');
      $("#botvoice").attr("src", "/Audios/" + result);
      audio.load();                 
      audio.play();
    }
  });
}
```

Controller side:

```
public ActionResult TextToSpeech(string text)
{
    string filename = "";
    try
    {
        AWSCredentials credentials = new StoredProfileAWSCredentials("my_credential");
        AmazonPollyClient client = new AmazonPollyClient(credentials, Amazon.RegionEndpoint.EUWest1);

        // Create describe voices request.
        DescribeVoicesRequest describeVoicesRequest = new DescribeVoicesRequest();
        // Synchronously ask Amazon Polly to describe available TTS voices.
        DescribeVoicesResponse describeVoicesResult = client.DescribeVoices(describeVoicesRequest);
        List<Voice> voices = describeVoicesResult.Voices;


        // Create speech synthesis request.
        SynthesizeSpeechRequest synthesizeSpeechPresignRequest = new SynthesizeSpeechRequest();
        // Text
        synthesizeSpeechPresignRequest.Text = text;
        // Select voice for synthesis.
        synthesizeSpeechPresignRequest.VoiceId = voices[18].Id;
        // Set format to MP3.
        synthesizeSpeechPresignRequest.OutputFormat = OutputFormat.Mp3;
        // Get the presigned URL for synthesized speech audio stream.

        string current_dir = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
        filename = CalculateMD5Hash(text) + ".mp3";
        var path_audio = current_dir + @"\Audios\" + filename;

        var presignedSynthesizeSpeechUrl = client.SynthesizeSpeechAsync(synthesizeSpeechPresignRequest).GetAwaiter().GetResult();

        FileStream wFile = new FileStream(path_audio, FileMode.Create);
        presignedSynthesizeSpeechUrl.AudioStream.CopyTo(wFile);
        wFile.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        filename = ex.ToString();
    }

    return Json(filename, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

An input text is present in my chat (obviously) for writing and sending (by pressing ENTER on the keyboard) the question to the bot. I tried to put the command `audio.src=""` in the handler, and she stops to talk but the chat still remains blocked... It seems like it waits the end of the audio stream. I have to refresh the page to see new messages and responses.

Is there any Amazon function that I can call with a particular parameter set, in order to notify the service that I want to stop and clear the audio stream?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Amazon Polly returns a `.mp3` file. It is not responsible for *playing* the audio file.

Any difficulties you are experiencing playing/stopping the audio would be the result of the code you are using to play an MP3 audio file. It has nothing to do with the Amazon Polly service itself.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you! 
 I found the real problem: when I stopped the audio I didn't print the rest of the messages. I add the call to the function that print messages on the chat. For stopping the voice I used the command audio.src="";